# How Vaadin-flow combobox works with value change listener?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

In my web application, I want to add some features like........

1. Combobox will be enabled when I select a pre-targeted value on another multi-select combo box(Combobox will disable first). 2. I have an enum class and set this data in two different combo box. If I select one data then it will no longer available for another combo box.

Any expert here or anyone who can give me some idea?

Answer (score 3):

Both of those use cases are not pre-implemented, you will have to implement this yourself. Both cases can be done by setting a ValueChangeListener on the first ComboBox.

To give an idea how this could look, here is an attempt at your first feature: disabling the second ComboBox when a value is selected in the first ComboBox

```
ComboBox<MyEnum> firstComboBox = new ComboBox<>();
ComboBox<MyEnum> secondComboBox = new ComboBox<>();

firstComboBox.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
    // disable second combobox if a value was chosen - enable if no value was chosen
    secondComboBox.setEnabled(event.getValue() == null);
});
```

You can find more examples of how to use ValueChangeListeners on ComboBoxes in the [ComboBox documentation](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/java-examples)

Comment: I have another question: I have a person type grid. In that person class, I have a userType Set. Now my question is how can I show this set in a format in that grid. (It shows like an array but i want to show just name)

Comment: @NirobRasseen Please open another question on Stackoverflow because it is a different topic. You could include some relevant code to make sure people can help you.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich I replied the same at first, but then I saw that [they did](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55391791/3441504) ;)